# Checksum failed for gitlab artefact

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

I struggle with Maven fetching dependency from Gitlab package repository:

- I run 'mvn clean install', then get:

```
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected '<!DOCTYPE' (REMOTE_EXTERNAL) but is >actually '86eb59572f3ab956e455569321e8a82df68bb7d1' from gitlab-maven for foo.jar
```

- and compilation then falls with:

```
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ChecksumFailureException: Checksum validation failed, >expected '<!DOCTYPE' (REMOTE_EXTERNAL) but is actually '37aa76a5d2b8d41249421e35470ca14c5e6a0b69'
   at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ChecksumValidator.validateExternalChecksums >(ChecksumValidator.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ChecksumValidator.validate (ChecksumValidator.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:484)
```

- My maven repository is configured like that:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.foo.bar/company_name/-/packages/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<distributionManagement>
     <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.foo.bar/company_name/-/packages</url>
     </repository>
     <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.foo.bar/company_name/-/packages</url>
     </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I added personal access token to my settings.xml, with all possible permissions to Gitlab repo:

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>*********</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
</servers>
```

It seems that foo.jar file is ok, since I am capable to load it on my own and install it using  **mvn install:install-file**
I would appreciate any advice to resolve the problem.